# Object method can not access Object variables?

Tags: java

I am trying to master the fundamentals of Java and OOP. From my understanding, if I have an object `Circle` that is instantiated with the variable radius, and passes that to a `double` x, should methods of the Object be able to access these?

```
package classes;

public class Circle {

    Circle(double radius) {
        double x = radius;
    }

    double area() {
        return x * x * 3.1415; // x can't be resolved to a variable
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is only available within the scope of the Circle constructor. Declare it at class level so it can be accessed by the `area` method

```
public class Circle {
    private double x;

    Circle(double radius) {
        this.x = radius;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `double x` is limited in scope to the constructor. If you move it out to the object level, it will work as you expect.

```
public class Circle {

    private double x;

    Circle(double radius) {
        this.x = radius;
    }

    double area() {
        return x * x * 3.1415; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a **scope** problem. When you declare `x` inside the constructor, you are telling that it will only be accessible inside it.

You may want to declare it outside:

```
public class Circle {
    double x;

    Circle(double radius) {
        x = radius;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After defined at class level use 'this' for readiblity.

```
public class Circle {
       private double x =0.0;
    Circle(double radius) {
        this.x = radius;
    }

    double area() {
        return this.x * this.x * 3.1415; // x can't be resolved to a variable
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
       public class Circle {
       private double x =0.0;
        Circle(double radius) {
    this.x = radius;
 }

double area() {
    return this.x *        this.x * Math.PI;
       }

 }
```